# Attempting to import Tensorflow keeps killing my Jupyter Notebook kernel

Tags: macos, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, apple-m1

It has previously worked before but when I go to import tensorflow in a Jupyter Notebook, it kills my kernel.

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

returns the following in the terminal for the notebook:

```
[I 12:49:56.507 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports
WARNING:root:kernel bf4af265-a31d-4f8e-9249-36cb3a73f31f restarted
```

```
pip list | grep tensorflow
```

returns

```
tensorflow                    2.13.0
tensorflow-estimator          2.13.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem  0.33.0
```

I'm aware of the current pages about this, however, I am having no luck with any of them.

I've recently been having compatibility errors with my M1 device and so have added a few lines into the ~/.zshrc (and since im new to computing could have messed up badly) so have attached that below too. I believe my fiddling must of messed something up! Hopefully someone can point out an error if there is one.

```
# Load pyenv (existing lines)
export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"

# Load conda (existing lines)
if [ -f "/Users/ioanevans/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
    . "/Users/ioanevans/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
else
    export PATH="/Users/ioanevans/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<

# Load Angular CLI autocompletion (existing lines)
# source <(ng completion script)

# Initialize Conda (replace with the correct path to your Anaconda/Miniconda installation)
export PATH="$HOME/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(conda shell.zsh hook)"

# Load pyenv and conda
export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$HOME/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
eval "$(conda shell.zsh hook)"
```

**EDIT:** I have tried
`conda install anaconda` but that outputs this:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: / 
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - defaults/osx-64::mkl_fft==1.3.6=py39h07fba90_1
  - defaults/osx-64::imbalanced-learn==0.10.1=py39hecd8cb5_1
  - defaults/osx-64::mkl_random==1.2.2=py39h07fba90_1
  - defaults/osx-64::_anaconda_depends==2023.03=py39_0
  - defaults/osx-64::notebook-shim==0.2.2=py39hecd8cb5_0
  - defaults/osx-64::jupyterlab_server==2.22.0=py39hecd8cb5_0
  - defaults/osx-64::tensorflow==2.10.0=eigen_py39h2f7e057_0
  - defaults/osx-64::nbclassic==0.5.5=py39hecd8cb5_0
  - defaults/osx-64::_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf==0.1.0=py39hecd8cb5_1
  - defaults/osx-64::jupyter==1.0.0=py39hecd8cb5_8
  - defaults/osx-64::notebook==6.5.2=py39hecd8cb5_0
  - defaults/osx-64::anaconda==custom=py39_1
  - defaults/osx-64::jupyterlab==3.5.3=py39hecd8cb5_0
unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: unsuccessful attempt using repodata from current_repodata.json, retrying with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: - unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

CondaError: KeyboardInterrupt
```

I assume I have a mismatch in download levels as Tensorflow is coming up as 2.13 and 2.10?

Comment: Deleted jupyter notebook and reinstalling fixed it.